# How to use undeclared variables in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-strict

I am creating a script node in my react code on run time using document.createElement('script') and assigning its src to a url,
Now I want to use the variable of the included JS in my react code without declaring it.

Comment: React is NodeJS server-based JavaScript, in which its functionalities can potentially conflict with direct DOM manipulation.  document.createElement('script') is doing browser-based direct DOM manipulation.  Directly-said, it is not the best practice to perform such in React's context.  Please research more about its architecture and limitations before performing direct DOM manipulation.  By the way, may I know the reason why you need to create script node in your react code?  What script is it?  Is it the script you wrote, or the scripts of JS libraries like JQuery/BootStrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define to the global like `window.yourVariable = 'value'` and then you can use.

```
window.globalVariable = {
   foo: 'bar',
};
```

```
const Component = () => {
   // you can access in here.
   return <div></div>
}
```